Contrast enhancing very faint extended blobs in an image
I have a series of images of the night sky and I'm looking for methods to enhance very faint structures that are barely visible. The movement of those structures is visible when you click through consecutive images but they're so faint and diffuse that it's hard to know where that feature is when you look at it.
I've included 5 images in this post; you can see the movement of white faint columnar features as you click through the images. I'm trying to find a way to bring them out, but methods like CLAHE and adaptive thresholding aren't working very well. I'm stumped and any help would be appreciated. The images are available at https://filebin.net/67p0de89oqx1b1sr.
Ideally I'd like a script that detects these features so I can apply the technique to many more images that I have, but I'm willing to do it by hand if a reproducible method is found. I suspect I'll have to do it by hand because of the diffusivity of the features.
(Crossposted from StackOverflow)
